# Аналог сцен из telegraf (js) в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, telegraf

Потрогал `NodeJS` с разработкой ботов под телеграм.
Очень сильно понравились сцены. Они невероятно удобные.
Есть ли их аналог в python?
Вообще, ориентируюсь под `aiogram`, но если они есть в других либрах, то тоже буду рад узнать о них.

## UPD 1:

Пример кода сцены:

```
on_welcome(){
        const _scene = new Scene('welcome')

        _scene.enter(async (ctx) => {
            await ctx.reply(core.msg['ru']['on_welcome'].format(name=ctx.from.username))
        })

        _scene.on('text', async (ctx) => {
            if (ctx.message.text) {
                //...
                _scene.leave();
            }else{
                //...
                _scene.reenter()
            }

        })
        //...
    }
```

То-есть, посылаем `enter message`, потом ставим `listener` на `text` и уже в хандлере мы можем либо запустить сцену заново из-за, допустим, некорректных данных, либо выйти со сцены.

Я очень долго бьюсь с этой проблемой в `python` и так и не нашел объективно простого и правильного решения.

В `python` у меня реализовано через `events`:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def on_any(message: Message):
    user = get_user(message.from_user.id)  # Получаем юзера из БД
    event: Event = get_user_event(message.from_user.id)  # Получаем возможный event юзера
    if event:
        if event.type == 'get_access':
            if VK.is_token_valid(message.text):
                if user:
                    update_user_token(message.text, user)
                else:
                    add_user(User(token=message.text, tg_id=message.from_user.id))
                del_event(id=message.from_user.id)  # Аналог _scene.leave()
                await message.answer(text=msg['on_good_token'], reply_markup=collect_new_pack())
            else:
                await message.answer(text=msg['on_bad_token'])  
        elif event.type == 'await_sticker':
                # ...
```

То-есть, юзер нажал на кнопку регистрации и должен отправить токен, допустим.
Моя реализация говорит о том, что на юзера вешается `event get_access`.
И в общем хандлеере всех сообщений я прохожусь по всем возможным `event'am`.

Comment: А что за сцены?

Comment: @gil9red , https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=stage

Comment: Это варианты декораторов(хэндлеров) - смотрите их

Comment: @SergBocharov, обновил вопрос. Если дадите пример реализации `telegraf.scene` из примера в вопросе на `aiogram` - буду очень признателен. Лучший ответ века будет.

Comment: Аналогом сцен, в питоничьих библиотеках, думаю, можно считать машины состояния (гуглите `state machine`). У aiogram это StatesGroup, у python telegram bot это ConversationHandler

Comment: Тогда и правда лучше использовать state machine, пример из документации посмотрите там все понятно - [здесь](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html)

Answer (score 1):

В aiogram это реализовано через [машину состояний](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter3.html)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)